# Greatest natural number which divides the determinant of a matrix

Tags: matrices, number-theory, determinant

All elements of a 100 x 100 matrix ,A are odd numbers. What is the greatest natural number that would always divide the determinant of A?

I have been able to show that it is always divisible by 2^99(y performing elementary row subtractions and additions) , but am stuck when it comes to showing that there is no natural number greater than this.

Comment: See [this MSE-question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231021/order-7-matrix-with-odd-entries-has-determinant-a-multiple-of-64) and do the same.

Comment: To show there is no larger number, calculate the determinant of a matrix with diagonal entries $n$ and all other entries $1$ and choose $n$ odd. Then vary $n$ to disqualify other factors.

Comment: @E.Lim could you please elaborate?

Comment: @DietrichBurde the mse question you directed to me seems to be asking to just prove that it is divisible by 2^n-1, i am more concerned wiht showing that ther can not be a greater integer than this

Comment: @Synonym For this you just give an example with determinant exactly equal to $2^{n-1}$ - this is not difficult.

Comment: @DietrichBurde But that does not look like a rigorous/general proof that there can be no greater integer

Comment: It does, because you wrote "that would *always* divide $\det(A)$".

Answer (score 0):

Consider the matrix,

$
M=
   \begin{bmatrix}
   1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
   1 & 3 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
   1 & 1 & 3 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
   \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots\\
   \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots\\
   \end{bmatrix}
$

This gives $2^{99}$ is the greatest natural number that would always divide the determinant.